# How can I make a view active among multiple views in RCP eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, rcp

I am building a RCP application in which I am using two views say viewA and viewB and one editor. I added listener to viewB which listens any selection from viewA and displays it, and I added one listener to editor which listens double click events from viewA and display the clicked details for editing. Here the problem is when I double click the viewA, details appear in editor for editing but after this viewB does not listen selection events until I click on viewB and make it active. Please suggest me some solution.

Comment: I think we need to see some code. Where are you setting up the selection listeners is viewB?

Comment: public void selectionChanged(IWorkbenchPart part, ISelection selection) {
  if(!selection.isEmpty()){
   showDetail(selection.toString());
  }
 }

Comment: ShowDetail Method is called to display details